# Get button class name or only name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button as follows

```
<input type='button' value='Generate' class="b1" name="b1" onclick='f1(this)'  />
```

Now I want to get the class name/ name b1 when i click on it.

So the output is `b1` showing in a alertbox

I have done following so far

```
function f1(objButton){  
    alert(objButton);
}
```

how can I do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
function f1(objButton){  
    alert(objButton.className);
    alert(objButton.name);
}
```

Updated for the name as well as className

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Hg6au/1/

Comment: You need to make sure the function is defined properly. Example here http://jsfiddle.net/Hg6au/1/ Using jQuery for something like this is like killing a fly with a rocket launcher.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the name

```
function f1(objButton){
  alert(objButton.getAttribute("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by jQuery:

```
  $('.b1').click(function(){
        var myClass = $('.b1').attr('class');
        alert(myClass);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `attr` function: (example given for name)

```
function f1(objButton) {
   alert($(objButton).attr('name'));
}
```

Comment: this also works but sean answered first so i am accepting his answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function f1(objButton){
alert($(objButton).attr("name"));
alert($(objButton).attr("class"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above only work for jQuery. If you don't wanna use jQuery you have to use the function getAttribute(). So:

```
function f1(objButton) {
    alert(objButton.getAttribute('name');
}
```

**UPDATE:** Was to slow...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function f1(objButton){  
    alert("Class Name = "+objButton.className);
    alert("Name = "objButton.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with jQuery:

```
function f1(){  
    var objButton = $("input.b1").attr('class');
    alert(objButton);
}


<input type='button' value='Generate' class="b1" name="b1" onclick='f1()'  />
```