# How to get CSS or XPath locator from a button class

Tags: css, class, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Button class and class locator details are only there.

It is not taking XPath or any locator value.

Please suggest any way on how to use button class.

```
<button class="btn btn-primaryr btn-block btn_wave">
    Sign Up
</button>
```

To get using XPath or CSS for it.

Comment: can you tell more detail about  the problem you are facing? because your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please confirm that your class is really `btn-primaryr` or if it should be `btn-primary`.

Comment: It is btn-primaryr !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get button class name or only name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874778/get-button-class-name-or-only-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an element using CSS you can try this:

```
diver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.btn_wave"));
```

This combines all classes from your button, BUT you can use just one of them and it might already be found, like this:

```
diver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-block.btn_wave"));
```

You can learn more about `selectors` googling it. They allow you to combine elements from your HTML and CSS classes.

One source to compare briefly with XPath is [here](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors).

Anyway, if you have more that one button in your page with the same CSS class, you might have to find a unique way to get it (using, for example the `:nth-child` selector).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is not selecting.

Comment: That's why is important to post your code in the question. `NullPointerException` is not because the element is not found. If Selenium can't find an element, it throws `NoSuchElementException - Element not found`. You have another problem in your code.

Comment: It is coming as No such element Exception now!!

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == button.btn-block btn_wave (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Sorry, I put a wrong space in the answer. The correct selector is `button.btn-block.btn_wave` (with `.` instead of a space). Just fixed it in the answer as well.

Comment: <button class="width-35 btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right btn-next btn_wave" ng-click="userSignUp();">

Comment: What is the difference in above comment mentioned html code and that I asked earlier.

Comment: Why selecting all classes does not get's executed but selecting particular get's it executed.